# How to pass over an element using TypeScript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to work out the position and the height/width of a DOM element through TypeScript/JQuery.
Before TypeScript I simply did something like this:

```
        function ActOnClick(itemClicked, loadPath) {
            //sample code
            var v1 = itemClicked.offset();
            var v2 = itemClicked.width();
            var v3 = itemClicked.height();

        };

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#idCRM").click(function () {
                ActOnClick($("#idCRM"), "/Widgets/GetCRM");
            });
}
```

where idCRM is a 'section' in my cshtml document (but it could be any div etc.)

Now I am trying to move this code into TypeScript but what type do I expect in the ActOnClick function to come in from the jQuery's $("#idCRM")?  Right now I choose 'Element' but a) it doesn't expose width, height etc and b) the ActOnClick call fails caused by the $("#idCRM")!

```
/// <reference path="../../ScriptsTS/jquery.d.ts" />
function ActOnClick(itemClicked: Element, loadPath: string) {

    var v1 = itemClicked.offset();  <-- FAILS
    var v2 = itemClicked.width();   <-- FAILS
    var v3 = itemClicked.height();  <-- FAILS

};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#idCRM").click(function () {
        ActOnClick($("#idCRM"), "/Widgets/GetCRM");  <-- FAILS
    });
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need the code to just work, you can always use the `Any` typescript type, like:

```
function ActOnClick(itemClicked: Any, loadPath: string) {
  var v1 = itemClicked.offset();
  var v2 = itemClicked.width();
  var v3 = itemClicked.height();
};
```

Typescript basically shuts up on an `Any` variable, and it won't issue any errors or warnings. However, `$("#idCRM")` should return an object that implements the `JQuery` interface, defined in `jquery.d.ts`, so you should actually use:

```
function ActOnClick(itemClicked: JQuery, loadPath: string) {
  var v1 = itemClicked.offset();
  var v2 = itemClicked.width();
  var v3 = itemClicked.height();
};
```

the `offset()`, `width()` and `height()` methods are defined on that interface, and they return `Object`, `number` and `number`, respectively.

Comment: my version (jquery-1.8.d.ts from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)) exposes a width method